# solr synonyms words with space issue

Tags: solr

I'm using `solr 6.3` and having problem in handling synonyms. My synonyms words are given below:

```
    sunglass => sun glass
    keychain => key chain
    keychain => key ring
    gemstone => gem stone
    sanitaryware => sanitary ware
    silverware => silver ware
```

but issue is when I search for 'sunglass' then keyword matching even only 'sun' also comes in the result but I want it should come only when all word matches means "sun glass". Same problems are with all the given words.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

this is a known, old issue. It had finally a good built in solution (before there were more convoluted improvements) in 6.5 or 6.6 aprox with SynonymGraphFilter and 'split on whitespace' option. Have a look at [this post](https://lucidworks.com/2017/04/18/multi-word-synonyms-solr-adds-query-time-support/), pick the newest Solr you can, and then go over all recommendations.

Comment: updated our solr version to 7.5. Now facing the different problem.
when search with product "baby doll" then find two results.
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":2,"params":{"q":"text:\"baby doll\"","sow":"true"}}"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[{ "product_slno":"3", "text":["babydoll","weblink"]},{"product_slno":"8","text":["baby doll","weblink"],]},when search with product "baby dolls" then find no results
{"responseHeader":{ "status":0,"QTime":1,"params":{"q":"text:\"baby dolls\"","sow":"true",}},"response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]}